# Angular list grouped by initial letters OR re-assign variable in template problem

Tags: angular, variable-assignment, ngfor, angular-template-variable

In Angular I have a long list of words which I display in template as `<li>` using `*ngFor` loop.
Because the list is so long, I want to make **sections by initial letter**. The list is already sorted alphabetically.

Usually I would have a variable for current letter. Then iterate the list and if the first letter of the current word does not equal the variable, I would display the new letter once in bold. Then I would re-assign the new letter to the variable and continue.

I sure can test `*ngIf` the current word's 1st letter equals the variable.
**However in Angular I cannot re-assigning that variable in template**.

What would be the best way to do this?

```
<div *ngFor="let word of list">
  <div *ngIf="initial !== word[0]">
    <!-- this does not work: {{ initial = word[0] }} -->
    <b>{{ word[0] }}</b>
  </div>
  <li>{{ word }}</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Performing operations in templates is not recommended.

I'd suggest you to prepare desired data structure in the component code and then render it using simple nested `*ngFor`.

In your case I'd probably use:

```js
groupOfWords: {
  initial: string,
  words: string[]
}[]
```

As an alternative you could have flat list with two types of elements (initial & word) - it depends on your usecase:

```js
items: ({ initial: string } | { word: string })[]
```